# Is it possbile to use databind value as id in aspx page

Tags: html, asp.net

I would like to name the id using  databind value n aspx page. My code is incorrect. Is it possbile to use dataind value as id in aspx page? If so, would someone tell me how to do it?

there is my script:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server"     id='<%# "hd" & Eval(Container.DataItem, "IDNum") %>' />
```

Comment: This is a guess, but I'd be a little surprised if you could set the `id` of a server-side control with the inline-block.  I'm assuming this hidden field is contained within a repeater of some variety, and therefore (assuming you're using non-static ids) it will be given a unique id based on the repeater item it is within

Comment: No, it cannot be done.